# get link from h1 tag and make image downloadable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i get link from the h1 tag and make image downloadable

```
<h1 data-source="image/image.jpg"><download Image</h1>
```

Actually i am using magnific-popup and need to show title and download link also. Since i already have anchor a i am not able to use another a inside anchor which makes sence. I am using header tags h1, h2, h3 to show title details and downlaod link but i want to make download h1 to work in a manner when user click it downloads the image rather than opening image in browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like below,

HTML:

```
<h1 data-source="image/image.jpg">download Image</h1>
<a style="display:none;" class="downloader" href="" download></a>
```

JS:

```
$("h1").click(function(){
 $(".downloader").attr("href", $(this).data("source"))[0].click();
});
```

**Concept :** Add a dummy `anchor` tag to your html with `display:none` and `download` attribute , And when user clicks on the `h1` tag set its `data-source` as `src` to that dummy anchor and trigger its natural click.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qj1mycxv/)

Comment: @Learning Pardon, I cannot understand what you are saying. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I tried almost every answer, it works for some of the solution but only once i have multiple image in the gallery, It click either for first item which i click and not the other element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` with `responseType` set to `"blob"`, `URL.createObjectURL()`, `download` attribute, `.click()`, `.remove()`

```
   $("h1").click(function() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.responseType = "blob";
      request.onload = function() {
        $("<a>", {
          id:"download",
          href:URL.createObjectURL(this.response)
        , download:""})
        .appendTo("body")[0].click();
        $("#download").remove();
      };
      request.open("GET", $(this).data().source);
      request.send()
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/medashiva/gzxvzazg/ try this hope helps

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("h1").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-source");
 })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<h1 data-source="image/image.jpg" id="download">download Image</h1>
```

CSS:

```
#download{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#download").click(function(e) {
  var link = $(this).data("source");
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = link;
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/9v7fwjc8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short plugin - [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)